# Store csv file data to MS Access Database with specific fields

Tags: java, ms-access

I have many files with huge data. I want to store that data to ms access database based on fields that is mentioned in csv file. The same fields data will be stored in database (I have four fields in database and same in csv field all data is going to store in database using Java).

[image]

In the above image I have 4 fields with huge data. I have created 4 fields in ms access database. In the created fields I want to insert all the data according to the fields in MS Access database.

I need a Java programming code to achieve this.

Comment: *I need a java programming code to achieve this*...unfortunately, SO is not a code-writing service. We are unpaid volunteers to help troubleshoot existing current efforts. Please read tutorials, give it a try, and come back with issues. Otherwise, hire a freelance coder.

Answer (score 0):

I will help you with reading from CSV file using OpenCSV lib ( I use version 3.8 of lib with Java 8).

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

import com.opencsv.CSVReader;


public class ReadCSV {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // The separator is ;
        CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("test.csv"),';');
        String [] nextLine;
        while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
            // nextLine[] is an array of values from the line
            System.out.println(nextLine[0] +" "+nextLine[1]+" "+nextLine[2]+" "+nextLine[3] );

        }
    }

}
```

I tested this code with test.csv and the separator is ;